# cshtml validation message text is removed via an unfamiliar jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom-events, jquery-events

I am running an MVC 5 web application with an auto-generated Entity Framework data model. It also uses JQuery and JQuery validate. 
I have a text box on a CRUD screen that must contain a decimal number with 5, 2 precision and scale, respectively.

JQuery validate does not have precision and scale validation, so I have to write a custom JavaScript function for this.

The function disables the submit button when the text box format is incorrect, and displays a message via the `@Html.ValidationMessage`inner-html text.

It all works, except when tabbing out of the text box field, the message text clears out.

Here is the text box:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WeeklyAccrual, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WeeklyAccrual, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "accrboxCreate", type = "number", onkeyup = "validateAccrualBox(this.value)", name = "weeklyAccruals" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WeeklyAccural, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "accrValidationMessageCreate" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the validation function:

```
function validateAccrualBox(v) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,5}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$");
    if (regex.test(v) || document.getElementById("accrboxCreate").value === "") {
        //allow text input
        console.log(v);
        console.log("Valid");
        document.getElementById("accrValidationMessageCreate").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("submitCreate").disabled=false;
    } else {
        //don't allow text input
        //display message "too many decimal places"
        console.log(v);
        console.log("Invalid");
        document.getElementById("accrValidationMessageCreate").innerHTML = "Correct format: 99999.99"
        document.getElementById("submitCreate").disabled=true;
    }

}
```

I have found that the culprit is a Jquery function:

```
if ( !(eventHandle = elemData.handle) ) {
            eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
                // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                return typeof jQuery !== core_strundefined && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
                    jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
                    undefined;
            };
            // Add elem as a property of the handle fn to prevent a memory leak with IE non-native events
            eventHandle.elem = elem;
        }
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Just use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute applied to your property (none of you scripts are required)

Comment: My data model is auto-generated through entity framework and will overwrite any manual changes I make to it. Sorry, I should have included that information.

Comment: Your editing data. You do **not** use data models in views - you always use view models. And a better alternative than a `[RegularExpression]` (which works with string) would be to write you own validation attribute - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)